# Android get data for contact using lookup key

Tags: android, contacts

I need to retrieve all data for a single contact which was chosen by a user (Action.Pick). I want to use LOOKUP KEY as suggested by developer.android.com. Can I do it by a simple query without creating Loader etc. as suggested by the documentation ?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this method for my application:

```
public static Cursor getContactCursorByLookUpKey(Context context,String lookUpKey)
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,lookUpKey);
    return contentResolver.query(lookupUri,null,null,null,null);
}
```

To get the data simply read data from the cursor. For example :

```
Cursor data = ContactManager.getContactCursorByLookUpKey(ContactDetailsActivity.this,lookUpKey);
String name = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
String photoPath = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI));
```

Comment: what happen if the lookUpKey change ?

Comment: If the `lookUpKey` changes, you will need to execute all of the code again.

Comment: Can we register ContentObserver for single contact entry ? I tried it but in onChange() method, i'm not getting the Uri of the changed contact, so that i can query that particular contact.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, No that's not possible. One approach to finding only the changed contact is to store the updated timestamp on your application database. Then on change, you make a query for the contact that has an update timestamp greater than the max update timestamp in your app database.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Contacts provider using `ContentResolver` directly, if you have the `READ_CONTACTS` permission. You will receive a cursor with multiple rows of raw contact details (phones, emails, etc.). Iterate over the cursor to read them and don't forget to close the cursor.